# Burndown chart in PowerBI showing curve for planned budget and actuals

Tags: powerbi, burndowncharts

I need to create a burndown chart like this one:

[image]

X-axis should be months. Y-axis hours. Blue curve is my planned budget in table "Budget" and red curve is actual spend hours in table "Actuals".

I have a dim_Date table that where date is related to date columns in both my "Budget" and "Actuals" table.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction? (no luck on the internet other than this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BElkIyAC-uQ but it only has one table)

[image]

Comment: Jesper without havin more details it is almost impossible to provide guidance. Where do hours come from, it's best practice for data modeling with Power BI to separate date and time into two columns with two dedicated dimension tables: calendar and time (hours).
Besides using the date dimension  for the axis and dragging the numeric columns from the actual and budget tables to the values bucket, what is the problem with your visualization?

Comment: I added my column visual that show budget and actuals for each month, but I would like to visualize it as a burn down chart instead (the blue and red one I just found on google to illustrate my goal)

Comment: Sum of all budget columns is 5571, so first point on blue line should be this number. Next point would be 5571 minus budget for january (626) = 5571-626 = 4945 and so forth.